# Working with elements between paper.setStart() and paper.setFinish() in Raphaels

Tags: javascript, raphael

Here's my question. Actualy it has two parts - firs ant second. Let's have for example this code.
I'm making a map which consists of regions (my coutry consists of regions and map is map of my country). So I wanna do something with whole map - like scaling, translate ... (the commented line).
And also I want to work with one each or just one part of the - so with one region. 
I'm new in Raphaels and also in javascript I just have no idea how to do it. So theres something like pseudocode of how I would do and obviously I should do it another and my question is how. So let's see the code bellow:

```
 window.onload = function() {
      var p = Raphael("paper");
      p.rect(0,0,600,350);

      p.setStart();
        var region1 = p.path("M404 ...");//I wont write all path here, "..." = rest of the path
        var region2 = p.path("M173.5 ...");
        //... rest of regions
      var map = p.setFinish();
      //map.scale(...).translate(...);// ... means just something correct is inthere

  //I wanna do first for example something like this
   map.region1.attr({
     fill: "blue"
   });
  //how should I do it?
  //Then second I would do also something like this
   for (region in map) {
      region.attr({//something...});
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the two main methods you probably want are..

```
set.forEach(function(e){
    //do something here on every element
})

set.transform('t100,100s2'); //translate and scale
```

I would have a rummage through the Raphael docs at http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html get some bits started and then post up a jsfiddle (you can add raphael lib on the left there) with any specific problems you are having.